# How to add a colorized HTML code snippet in Sandcastle documentation?

Tags: sandcastle, maml

I am using the Sandcastle Help File Builder and would like to include colorized HTML code snippets in the "Conceptual Content".  Is this possible and if so, how?

I have tried <code>, <codeExample>, and <sampleCode language="HTML" />.

The best result so far is to HTML-encode the sample HTML and place it in a .snippets file like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<examples>
   <item id="htmlSnippet">
      <sampleCode language="HTML">
         &lt;span&gt;My Html&lt;/span&gt;
      </sampleCode>
   </item>
</examples>
```

Then reference it in the .aml file.

```
<codeReference>htmlSnippet</codeReference>
```

I would prefer to have it colorized, but I can't figure out a way to add the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MAML Guide](http://www.ewoodruff.us/mamlguide/?topic=html/65e7e30a-ba03-4e10-b1f2-763a613b6e27.htm), the proper way of doing this is to use a `<code>` tag with a `CDATA` section:

```
<code language="xml" title="Example Configuration">
<![CDATA[
    <span>My Html</span>]]>
</code>
```

The contents of the CDATA section will be treated as a literal string, and indentation will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but Sandcastle supports html as `xml`.  I figured I should comment in case anyone else comes across this post as I did.

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<examples>
   <item id="htmlSnippet">
      <sampleCode language="xml"><!CDATA[[
         <span>My Html</span>
       ]]>
      </sampleCode>
   </item>
</examples>
```

If you're using Sandcastle Help File Builder, you may create your own syntax parser as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16740/Creating-Custom-Build-Components-for-Sandcastle) and  [here](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/c18d6cb6-e4e4-4944-84ee-f867aa6cfb0d.htm), although xml is available by default... using the XAML filter's generator, which is defined here if you want to look at the config:

```
<generator type="Microsoft.Ddue.Tools.XamlUsageSyntaxGenerator"
    assembly="{@SandcastlePath}ProductionTools\SyntaxComponents.dll">
    <filter files="{@SandcastlePath}Presentation\Shared\configuration\xamlSyntax.config" />
</generator>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the SHFB documentation for the [Code Block Component](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/7f03ba39-09f8-4320-bdbd-ed31a3bd885f.htm), you should be able to just use the `<code>`.

I got it to work without a problem; here's what I did:

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>Something!</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
<!-- #region myhtml -->
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <div>Div for <strong>Good</strong> <em>measure</em>.</div>
<!-- #endregion -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**SomethingorOther.aml**

```
<code language="html" source="../Examples/test.html" region="myhtml" />
```

Result:

[image: HTML Highlighting in SHFB]

Please note that in the preview, your sample will appear as unhighlighted XML, but when you build the documentation, everything should like just fine.